# Rotating a bone along one of its local axes

Tags: rigging

I am doing a complex mechanical hand rig and i want to rotate one of the bones along its x axis but Blender doesnt allow me to do that. Is there a way to do that or this type of rotation isnt supported by the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried hitting X one extra time? eg. <kbd>R</kbd> >> <kbd>X</kbd> >> <kbd>X</kbd>". Maybe you have to do two <kbd>Y</kbd>'s OR two <kbd>Z</kbd>'s but one of these options should get you there.

Here are bones rotating in their local axis.

[image]

If you are in Edit Mode, X May be close to equal (global vs. local).
Instead try Y & Z:

[image]

Comment: I know of that way to rotate along local axes but it wont rotate at its local axis( i just tried that). The only way i found for it to work is to create custom orientations and then rotate the bone the way you want. Normally hitting the axis letter twice should work but with objects only, not bones

Comment: Are you in Edit Mode trying to do this? If you are, it's probably because of your weights on the hand mesh.

Comment: Actually in Edit Mode, It may be considering Local & Global X The same thing. Try Y & Z.

Comment: Thanks guys for your answers and time. I figured it out. There were not any weights because i'm doing a mechanical rig...